# printing an object in javascript similar to the way we print an object in Java

Tags: javascript

I want to print data of an object in JavaScript. By defining a function and calling that function, i'm able to do that. To call such function i'm using **s.show()** in my code. But what i want is... by just specifying **s** [ like **document.write(s)** ], i want to print the object. In Java language, when we try to print an object, the System.out.println() calls the toString() method on that object. Is there any way in JavaScript?

Please help. Thanks in Advance.

```
<script>
function stud(a,b,c)
{
  this.one=a;
  this.two=b;
  this.three=c;
  this.show=function toString()
    {
        document.write(a+","+b+","+c+"<br>");
    }
}
var s=new stud("smile","laugh","cry");
s.show(); // this is working
document.write(s); // i want this also work same
</script>
```

Comment: if you need this just for logging purposes, consider `console.log(s)`.

Comment: `document.write(JSON.stringify(s));`

Comment: JSON.stringify() is displaying the object's **properties** and **values** but i want only the values to be printed. any help?

Answer (score 1):

You can print any Javascript Object by using its logging functions.

There are basic 3 functions for loging

```
console.log( s ); // You can use this one.
```

Or you can parse your object like this also.

```
function stud(a,b,c)
{
  this.one=a;
  this.two=b;
  this.three=c;
  this.show=function toString()
  {
     // This will print your json as string as print in JAVA.
     document.write( JSON.stringify(this) );
  }
}
```

Input:

```
var s=new stud("smile","laugh","cry");
s.show(); // this is working
```

Output:

```
{"one":"smile","two":"laugh","three":"cry"}
```

Comment: the JSON.stringify() is displaying both **properties** and **values** of the object. But I want only the **values** of the object. I mean, the _toString() of my code_ should be called when i try to display the object (using 'docuement.write(s)') to the user.